# f:loadBundle loading the properties file outside the war , through JVM param?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, resourcebundle

the `f:loadBundle` featue is cool, but does it only load prop files which are inside the war file ? I have to load the properties file from JVM from a different location and manage the prop file outside the war. Can I take leverage of `f:loadBundle` in this case ?
Or is there any other util which allows that ?

Comment: I have the same question.. No answer to this?